# Windows SBS 2008 has two DC's, what will happen if the master crashes

Tags: windows-server-2008

This is the first time I am doing this sort of configuration on a windows Env. Hailing from a strong linux background , I just wanted to check on what the expected outcome was.

Its a network of about 20 PC's which had 1 Domain Controller (Server 1), A hard drive crash and a recovery kept it half dead and most of the Snap-ins did now work. I configured a new DC on a different machnine (Server 2) and promoted it as a domain controller. So now there are 2 Domain controllers but all the FSMO's are still on Server 1. However due to the instability of Server 1 I am not sure whether the replication completed successfully. ( Note:- most of the users in ADUS are not in SBS console when checked on Server 2) .

My question would be, If i am to physically pull out the Network cable of Server 1 Who has all the current FSMO's would Server 2 automatically be promoted to these FSMO's

I checked for several days on the internet to find a similar scenario, All the topics were about demoting server1, but i would like to have a fallback plan where I can plug the cable back in and remove server 2 from the network

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question would be, If i am to physically pull out the Network cable
>   of Server 1 Who has all the current FSMO's would Server 2
>   automatically be promoted to these FSMO's

No the FSMO roles will not be automatically moved.

If you move the FSMO roles from one DC to another while the domain controllers are both healthy and operational, this is called *transferring* the FSMO roles gracefully, and is the preferred method.

If you move the FSMO roles after the original FSMO role holder is permanently offline, or off the network, this is called forcefully *seizing* the FSMO roles, and is considered a last resort.

Either way, you must do this manually.

**And one very important tip -- if you seize the FSMO roles from the old DC you must never, ever bring the old domain controller back online on the network.** Doing so usually causes a USN rollback, which can be a real pain to remediate and basically leave your AD forest in even worse shape than it was before.

You may or may not need to seize the roles  - we do not have enough information to know that for sure. You would start by using repadmin.exe and dcdiag.exe to determine if your forest is healthy enough to gracefully transfer FSMO roles.

You can transfer FSMO roles through the GUI, or through NTDSUTIL. However, you can seize only via ntdsutil.

[Seizing FSMO roles](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255504)

You should try gracefully transferring the roles first since you don't really know how good or bad shape your AD domain is in. Active Directory will tell you if the conditions aren't right for the roles to be transferred gracefully.

(I sound like a pharmaceutical ad - ask your contractor if transferring FSMOs is right for you. Do not transfer FSMOs if you're not healthy enough for this type of activity...)

Comment: I totally understand , this being the first task of my new job :) . The problem is the existing domain controller is in a bad state that none of the snap-ins work  and many other problems. I have successfully added another newly built domain controller and both of them are succesfully replicated. If all goes well we will be demoting the Original Domain controller and leaving the the secondary one as the primary domain controller. (Im thinking whether to switch it so that it doe not cause any problems ). Let me do some tests using the tools you suggested !! thanks for your response

Comment: One Question though ?, What is the purpose of having 2 domain controllers if they cannot converge on their own ?

Comment: @niroshan.l Active Directory is, in general, a distributed system. It performs many functions, such as authentication and data replication, in a multi-master fashion. If 50% of my domain controllers go down, I can still logon on the domain using the remaining 50% of the DCs. Data can still be replicated among the remaining 50% of the DCs. But of all the things that DCs do, there are a distinct handful of operations that must *not* be distributed. They must be single master operations. Hence, FSMOs. Read up on FSMOs to see what those few operations are specifically.

Comment: Thanks for your response, and please do apoligize my ignorance as I am completely new to the Windows Env... Yes I agree that if a DC is not functioning the other Master DC's will continue to serve the network, but What my concern is, even if there are many Master DC's on the domain, If the DC having the FSMO goes down physically what will happen to these tasks, if any other DC's are not automatically assigned these roles ? Say the Schema master goes down, Who will handle the replication of this information since other DC's can make schema changes ?

Comment: @niroshan.l No problem - we are all here to learn and most of us (except maybe TomTom) are happy to help. If the DC holding the FSMOs goes down, functions offered by the FSMOs will be unavailable. These functions include password resets, extending the schema, adding new domains to the forest, issuing new RID pools to DCs, etc. Replication will still happen though. (Including replication of the existing schema, as you mention.) Think of it as kind of like your domain going into "read-only" mode while the FSMOs are down.

Comment: Ohhh, It makes sense now. Fair enough. I guess now i have a better picture of how the DC's will behave when a certain action is taken. Thanks for the detailed explanation.  Cheers Niro